# Converting table to new format

Tags: lua

Hello I have 2 tables with the following formats:

**This is the old table format**

```lua
male = {
        tshirt_1 = 15, tshirt_2 = 0,
        torso_1 = 241, torso_2 = 0,
        decals_1 = 0, decals_2 = 0,
        arms = 0, arms_2 = 0,
        pants_1 = 98, pants_2 = 4,
        shoes_1 = 80, shoes_2 = 1,
        glasses_1 = 0, glasses_2 = 0,
        helmet_1 = 77, helmet_2 = 19,
        chain_1 = 0, chain_2 = 0,
        ears_1 = -1, ears_2 = 0
    },
```

**This is the new table format**

```lua
male = {
            props = {
                ["1"] = {"glasses", -1},
                ["2"] = {"earrings", -1},
                ["3"] = {"mouth", -1},
                ["4"] = {"lhand", -1},
                ["5"] = {"rhand", -1},
                ["6"] = {"watches", -1},
                ["7"] = {"braclets", -1},
                ["0"] = {"hats", 19} 
            },
        
            drawtextures = {
                {"face", 0},
                {"masks", 0},
                {"hair", 0},
                {"torsos", 0},
                {"legs", 4},
                {"bags", 0},
                {"shoes", 1},
                {"neck", 6},
                {"undershirts", 0},
                {"vest", 0},
                {"decals", 0},
                {"jackets", 0},
            },
        
            drawables = {
                ["1"] = { "masks", 0 },
                ["3"] = { "torsos", 0 }, -- ARMS
                ["4"] = { "legs", 98 }, -- PANTS
                ["5"] = { "bags", 0 },
                ["6"] = { "shoes", 80 },
                ["7"] = { "neck", 0 }, -- CHAIN
                ["8"] = { "undershirts", 15}, -- T SHIRT
                ["9"] = { "vest", 0 },
                ["10"] = {"decals", 0},
                ["11"] = { "jackets",  280 }, -- TORSO
            },
        
            proptextures = { { "hats", 77 }, { "glasses", -1 }, }
        },
```

So for example I am trying to match `tshirt_1` from table 1 to `drawables[8][15]` in table 2. 15 is the value of tshirt_1 in table 1. If you could help me get started with the first one to convert I should be able to do the rest.

**What I have so far** (yes I am very confused on the logic, don't make fun of me lol)

```lua
local oldJobs = {
    test1 = {
        tshirt_1 = 15, tshirt_2 = 0,
        torso_1 = 241, torso_2 = 0,
        decals_1 = 0, decals_2 = 0,
        arms = 0, arms_2 = 0,
        pants_1 = 98, pants_2 = 4,
        shoes_1 = 80, shoes_2 = 1,
        glasses_1 = 0, glasses_2 = 0,
        helmet_1 = 77, helmet_2 = 19,
        chain_1 = 0, chain_2 = 0,
        ears_1 = -1, ears_2 = 0,
        bproof_1 = 0, bproof_2 = 0
    }
} 

local newJobs = {}


function run()
    for i = 0, #oldJobs do
        local testing = [[
            props = {
                ["1"] = {"glasses", ]] .. oldJobs[i].glasses_1 .. [[},
                ["2"] = {"earrings", -1},
                ["3"] = {"mouth", -1},
                ["4"] = {"lhand", -1},
                ["5"] = {"rhand", -1},
                ["6"] = {"watches", -1},
                ["7"] = {"braclets", -1},
                ["0"] = {"hats", ]] .. oldJobs[i].helmet_2 .. [[} 
            },
        
            drawtextures = {
                {"face", 0},
                {"masks", 0},
                {"hair", 0},
                {"torsos", 0},
                {"legs", ]] .. oldJobs[i].pants_2 .. [[},
                {"bags", 0},
                {"shoes", ]] .. oldJobs[i].shoes_2  .. [[},
                {"neck", ]] .. oldJobs[i].chain_2  .. [[},
                {"undershirts", ]] .. oldJobs[i].tshirt_2  .. [[},
                {"vest", ]] .. oldJobs[i].bproof_2  .. [[},
                {"decals", 0},
                {"jackets", ]] .. oldJobs[i].torso_2  .. [[},
            },
        
            drawables = {
                    ["1"] = { "masks", 0 },
                    ["3"] = { "torsos", ]] .. oldJobs[i].arms  .. [[ }, -- ARMS
                    ["4"] = { "legs", ]] .. oldJobs[i].pants_1  .. [[ }, -- PANTS
                    ["5"] = { "bags", 0 },
                    ["6"] = { "shoes", ]] .. oldJobs[i].shoes_1  .. [[},
                    ["7"] = { "neck", ]] .. oldJobs[i].chain_1  .. [[ }, -- CHAIN
                    ["8"] = { "undershirts", ]] .. oldJobs[i].tshirt_1  .. [[}, -- T SHIRT
                    ["9"] = { "vest", ]] .. oldJobs[i].bproof_1  .. [[ },
                    ["10"] = {"decals", 0},
                    ["11"] = { "jackets",  ]] .. oldJobs[i].torso_1  .. [[}, -- TORSO
                },
            
            proptextures = { { "hats", ]] .. oldJobs[i].helmet_1  .. [[ }, { "glasses", ]] .. oldJobs[i].glasses_1 .. [[ }, }
        ]]
        table.insert(newJobs, testing)
    end
print((testing))
end

run()
```

I know it's not complete bc I just figured I didn't know what I was doing and could do much more if I got some guidance on how to accomplish this.

Comment: I cannot follow you. why don't you just hardcode this? I mean there's no obvious order in any of those tables.

Answer (score 0):

So to do this I just did come `concat`

```lua
local oldJobs = {
    test1 = {
        tshirt_1 = 15, tshirt_2 = 0,
        torso_1 = 241, torso_2 = 0,
        decals_1 = 0, decals_2 = 0,
        arms = 0, arms_2 = 0,
        pants_1 = 98, pants_2 = 4,
        shoes_1 = 80, shoes_2 = 1,
        glasses_1 = 0, glasses_2 = 0,
        helmet_1 = 77, helmet_2 = 19,
        chain_1 = 0, chain_2 = 0,
        ears_1 = -1, ears_2 = 0,
        bproof_1 = 0, bproof_2 = 0
    }
} 

local newJobs = {}


function run()
    for i = 0, #oldJobs do
        local testing = [[
            props = {
                ["1"] = {"glasses", ]] .. oldJobs[i].glasses_1 .. [[},
                ["2"] = {"earrings", -1},
                ["3"] = {"mouth", -1},
                ["4"] = {"lhand", -1},
                ["5"] = {"rhand", -1},
                ["6"] = {"watches", -1},
                ["7"] = {"braclets", -1},
                ["0"] = {"hats", ]] .. oldJobs[i].helmet_2 .. [[} 
            },
        
            drawtextures = {
                {"face", 0},
                {"masks", 0},
                {"hair", 0},
                {"torsos", 0},
                {"legs", ]] .. oldJobs[i].pants_2 .. [[},
                {"bags", 0},
                {"shoes", ]] .. oldJobs[i].shoes_2  .. [[},
                {"neck", ]] .. oldJobs[i].chain_2  .. [[},
                {"undershirts", ]] .. oldJobs[i].tshirt_2  .. [[},
                {"vest", ]] .. oldJobs[i].bproof_2  .. [[},
                {"decals", 0},
                {"jackets", ]] .. oldJobs[i].torso_2  .. [[},
            },
        
            drawables = {
                    ["1"] = { "masks", 0 },
                    ["3"] = { "torsos", ]] .. oldJobs[i].arms  .. [[ }, -- ARMS
                    ["4"] = { "legs", ]] .. oldJobs[i].pants_1  .. [[ }, -- PANTS
                    ["5"] = { "bags", 0 },
                    ["6"] = { "shoes", ]] .. oldJobs[i].shoes_1  .. [[},
                    ["7"] = { "neck", ]] .. oldJobs[i].chain_1  .. [[ }, -- CHAIN
                    ["8"] = { "undershirts", ]] .. oldJobs[i].tshirt_1  .. [[}, -- T SHIRT
                    ["9"] = { "vest", ]] .. oldJobs[i].bproof_1  .. [[ },
                    ["10"] = {"decals", 0},
                    ["11"] = { "jackets",  ]] .. oldJobs[i].torso_1  .. [[}, -- TORSO
                },
            
            proptextures = { { "hats", ]] .. oldJobs[i].helmet_1  .. [[ }, { "glasses", ]] .. oldJobs[i].glasses_1 .. [[ }, }
        ]]
        table.insert(newJobs, testing)
    end
print((testing))
end

run()
```

and this worked.